# List RTSP streams of network camera

Tags: video, rtsp, ip-camera

I have just puchased a Micronet SP5319 HD IP camera and there is no info in the documentation regarding the path of the streams. I only found something like rtsp://ip/mpeg4 but in the end it does not work. I have tried many different paths with many different clients such as VLC and QuickTime. No success.

I wiresharked the stream and it look like:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.90:554/h264 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.4 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.09.13)

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Date: Tue, Dec 04 2012 01:12:36 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, GET_PARAMETER, SET_PARAMETER

DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.90:554/h264 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.4 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2012.09.13)
Accept: application/sdp

RTSP/1.0 404 Stream Not Found
CSeq: 3
Date: Tue, Dec 04 2012 01:12:36 GMT
```

Look at the last response: Stream Not Found. Finally, how can I get a list of available streams? Which software should I use? I have also tried with ONVIF without success.

Best regards,

Comment: Inquire Micronet about device caps (reference, API, SDK etc), there is no RTSP command to enumerate resources on a device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that this camera works over SDK. But you can try to do the following actions:

- Open Wireshark and setup filter for camera's IP;
- Open the camera's web-interface and get video;
- Look at the Wireshark session -  possible, there is RTSP-session.

http://yummy.micronet.tw/marcom/enews/071312/071312.htm - here I can see that camera supports ONVIF, so, it must support RTSP
And here http://yummy.micronet.tw/marcom/enews/point/SP5319-catalog.pdf - i can see supported protocols too - RTSP is included.

So, if the web-interface doesn't help you, you can test your camera over ONVIF Test Tool and you can find RTSP-addresses here.

And check, please, RTSP port in the web-interface - is it really 554?

Comment: Finally I found the correct path! it was /master.sdp thanks for your suggestions Dmitriy.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue, after reading tons of blogs, I find some interesting resources:

1) [Here](https://security.world/rtsp/) there is a huge list of rstp known URLs for certain brands. Unfortunately, mine wasn't there (the brand is kolke, if you wonder...)

2)[This table](https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=china) shows different URLs for other cameras models. I tried several of them, without success. It was time consuming to do it with VLC, since I had to write one by one, so I wrote a small python script to test each of them with opencv and run it on a jupyter notebook:

```py
import cv2

# need to know those before hand. I got IP with Nmap
usr = 'myuser'
pwd = 'mypassword'
ip = '192.168.1.1'

# I took the url patterns and also included some variations, just to be sure...
urls = [f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/live=2.2&username={usr}&password={pwd}',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/1',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/stream1',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/Stream1',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/videostream.asf?user={usr}&pwd={pwd}',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/ucast/11',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/11',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/12',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/live0.264',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/mpeg4cif',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/live1.264',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/cam1/h264',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/mpeg4cif',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/ucast/11',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/ROH/channel/11',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}_password={pwd}_channel=1_stream=0.sdp',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}_password={pwd}_channel=1_stream=0.sdp',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}_password={pwd}_channel=1_stream=0.sdp?',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/cam1/mpeg4?user={usr}&pwd={pwd}',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/h264_stream',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/live/ch0',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/live/ch1',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=1&stream=1.sdp?',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=0&stream=1.sdp?',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=0&stream=0.sdp?',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=1&stream=1.sdp',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=0&stream=1.sdp',
        f'rtsp://{ip}:554/user={usr}&password={pwd}&channel=0&stream=0.sdp',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/ucast/11',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/11',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/12',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/live0.264',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/mpeg4cif',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/live1.264',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/cam1/h264',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/mpeg4cif',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/ucast/11',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/ROH/channel/11',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/h264_stream',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/live/ch0',
        f'rtsp://{usr}:{pwd}@{ip}:554/live/ch1',
       ]

def test_url(url):
    # try to open the stream
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    ret = cap.isOpened()  # if it was succesfully opened, that's the URL you need
    cap.release()
    return ret

# then you just need to check those URLs
for url in urls:
    if test_url(url):
        print(url)
```

And then I got what I've been looking for:

```
rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/user=myuser&password=mypassword&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?
```

Hope it helps!